Wait time at "creation of DexInterface pending" process
I've deployed a smart contract via Remix with MetaMask as the injected provider. I'm getting the message "creation of DexInterface pending" but have no idea how long I should expect to wait or if the network is just jammed - or whatever.  Any ideas?

Have you retried after reloading/refreshing the Remix tab?

Yes indeed, thank you.  The smart contract deployed but did not have the intended effect. Still trying to troubleshoot.
